# Making Google extension which can save to google drive

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-drive-api

I looked thru the internet and didn't found a solution how to make this:

I want to make google extension which will use Google API or something to connect the extension to Google drive and create/update files there( i will need mostly plain text documents to store there arrays). i will need it only for personal use, so any hacks are also acceptable.

Have anyone done anything like this before? i just need the starting point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have made an example that is available on Github. [It is available here](https://github.com/dhatanian/demo-gmail-api). It transforms the some emails from GMails into PDFs stored in Drive.

You can reuse it, you simply need to copy the Drive part and not the GMail API part. The steps you'll need to follow are :

1. Use the Chrome identity API to retrieve an access token for the Drive API
2. Use the Drive API javascript client to upload your text files. The tricky part is to upload it properly, use the examples on the github project to see what the request should look like.